# Upgrade Phonegap/Cordova 2.0 to 3+

Tags: cordova

Any good tips, clear guidelines or experience upgrading an old phonegap project?

We have a fairly robust application running on Cordova 2.0.0 .  In attempting to upgrade to the current 3.5 version, a large amount of folder structure changes is necessary.

Working from the documention here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html

It appears the important files to transfer and vital steps are:

- www directory
- src directory
- res directory
- install plugins from CLI

Yet with that, we're still having trouble even getting the project to run in the browser or build with Cordova CLI or our custom any build.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I never used v2.x and started with version 3+ so I can't relate to your story but the folder structure you describe (www, src, res, ...) is indeed of paramount importance when building Phonegap/Cordova 3+ app so I wonder if you wouldn't be better off starting a new phonegap/cordova project from scratch and importing code and static resources along the way rather than literally migrating from 2.0 to 3+.

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful to get more details.

1. what platforms does your project target?
2. what plugins does your project consume?
3. does your project have any custom native code?
4. does your project modify the native cordova implementation?
5. what are the actual errors you receive when building the app with the PhoneGap CLI?

some things that might help:

#### no custom native

If your project is purely webtech, then the problem is likely how your project consumes the cordova api's. Things have changed all over the project since 2.0.0 and I would have to answer on a api by api basis.

#### custom native code

this could be why the build fails, and again, answers vary based on the compiler errors you receive from the native build system